# Azure Automation State Configuration: Where to see if apply and autocorrect was successful on OS side?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, dsc

Currently testing a DSC that ensures DHCP is always enabled on Azure VMs. Running in apply and monitor works fine and will warn when a machine is not complaint and the VM will still remain up, although running Apply and autocorrect will freeze up machine and I believe run the DSC and it will work then. Although nothing is proving that in Azure Automation logs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Network Interface that is allocated the IP address. The VM uses the network interface.

Therefore you can use:

```
Get-AzNetworkInterface
   [-Name <String>]
   [-ResourceGroupName <String>]
```

In the output you should see:

> "PrivateIpAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"

Which confirms that DHCP was used